# Select required members only by default when implementing interface with Pick generic type

Tags: javascript, typescript, jetbrains-ide

I use the following Generic type.

```
interface Bar {
    bar: number,
    foo: number,
    baz?: number
}

class Foo implements Pick<Bar, 'foo' | 'baz'> {

}
```

When I try to use the suggestion to import missing implementation, it selects all members as required by default. How to select only those that are required by default?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to identifying the Optional keys at https://gist.github.com/eddiemoore/7873191f366675e520e802a9fb2531d8 but I have no idea how it works, even after studying it for quite a while. Tried to simplify the implementation as it seems to have a lot of stuff it doesn't need, but I have failed. It works, but is magic.

```
type Undefined<T> = { [P in keyof T]: P extends undefined ? T[P] : never }

type FilterFlags<Base, Condition> = {
  [Key in keyof Base]:
  Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
};

type AllowedNames<Base, Condition> =
  FilterFlags<Base, Condition>[keyof Base];

type SubType<Base, Condition> =
  Pick<Base, AllowedNames<Base, Condition>>;

type OptionalKeys<T> = Exclude<keyof T, NonNullable<keyof SubType<Undefined<T>, never>>>

//BLACK MAGIC IMPLEMENTATION ABOVE

interface Bar {
    bar: number,
    foo: number,
    baz?: number
}

type OptionalBar = OptionalKeys<Bar>;

class Foo implements Omit<Bar,OptionalKeys<Bar>>  {

}
```